# Java synchronized block: Lock block until object instantiated

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, synchronized

I want to synchronize a block of my code and release it only when the object connection has been instantiated, how can I do that?

```
public void myMethod() {

 Connection connection = null;

 synchronized (connection) {
 // Set configuration, block of code to synchronize
 }

 connection = getConnection(configuration); // Should be released after this
}
```

Comment: It's not good practise to synchronize on an object that is non final - consider synchronizing at the method level or on the class that myMethod lives in. Your choice will depend on what else lives in this class and what performance you require.

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate thing as your monitor:

```
private final Object myMethodLock = new Object();

public void myMethod() {

 Connection connection = null;

 synchronized (myMethodLock) {
   connection = getConnection(configuration);
 }

 // myMethodLock has been released.
}
```